# Backticks with su -c in SSH Command without running command in it

Tags: linux, ssh, su

I have a little question:

I want to echo something in the Crontab an several Servers, with Backticks.
Heres my sample command:

```
for server in $( cat list ); do ssh -t $user@$server "su -c \"echo '35 * * * * $script_that_runs ''\'\`/bin/hostname\`''\'  $Parameter2 $Parameter3' >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root \" "; done
```

On the Remoteserver it shows up like:

```
35 * * * * $script_that_runs '$hostname'  $Parameter2 $Parameter3
```

But i want it that way:

```
35 * * * * $script_that_runs `/bin/hostname`  $Parameter2 $Parameter3
```

I havent found an answer yet. Maybe im just to silly atm to find one.
Has anybody got an solution for this?

Problems were:

- if i run su -c with single quotes, it won't work
- if im not escaping the echo command every file in the actual directory will be echo'd in the crontab.

Command with best result:

```
for server in $( echo $servername ); do ssh -t $user@$server "su -c \"echo '35 * * * * /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/nsca_wrapper \`\`/bin/hostname\`\`  apt-check /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_apt' >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root \" "; done
```

Comment: I guess you need to double-escape the ` character, since it is evaluated twice. Once in your terminal and for the second time on the remote one.

Comment: Seems not to work for me. (Result: /bin/hostname instaed of `/bin/hostname` (It is without Backticks) )

Comment: just tried exactly your code and I am getting syntax errors.Can you provide please minimal example without for cycle, variable and stuff, that would work?

Comment: @Jakuje, i've edited my post below. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should double-escape the

```
`
```

character like this

```
\\\`
```

Example with minimal code:

```
 $ ssh -t host "su -c \"echo 'something \\\`/bin/hostname\\\`' > /tmp/test \"; cat /tmp/test ";
 something `/bin/hostname`
```

Comment: I thought I've tried that already. nvm.
It works now. Thank you :-D